# Downloaded and uploaded values

Tags: deluge

[image]

What do the numbers in brackets mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is included in the FAQ.

Comment: Not everyone reads the FAQ. Exhibit A: you and this question. Leave the question so others can find the answer the same was you did, except without having to ask it themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number in parentheses is the amount downloaded during the current session.

Deluge FAQ provides a section called ["What do all those numbers in parentheses mean?"](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#Whatdoallthosenumbersinparenthesesmean) Which came up following a questions on their forum about it in around 2008.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that when I looked through the UI section of the FAQ earlier.